# Using scala play-json 2.4.x, how do I extract the name of a json object into a different object?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Given this json:

```json
{
  "credentials": {
    "b79a2ba2-lolo-lolo-lolo-lololololol": {
      "description": "meaningful description",
      "displayName": "git (meaningful description)",
      "fullName": "credential-store/_/b79a2ba2-lolo-lolo-lolo-lololololol",
      "typeName": "SSH Username with private key"
    }
  },
  "description": "Credentials that should be available irrespective of domain specification to requirements matching.",
  "displayName": "Global credentials (unrestricted)",
  "fullDisplayName": "Credentials » Global credentials (unrestricted)",
  "fullName": "credential-store/_",
  "global": true,
  "urlName": "_"
}
```

and this scala destination class:

```scala
case class JenkinsCredentials(uuid: String, description: String)
```

How can I create a `Reads[JenkinsCredentials]` to extract that first object name uuid `b79a2ba2-lolo-lolo-lolo-lololololol` along with the description?

Following the documentation it'd be something along the lines of this:

```scala
implicit val credsReader: Reads[JenkinsCredentials] = (
  (JsPath).read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "description").read[String]
  )(JenkinsCredentials.apply _)
```

Used with `(Json.parse(content) \\ "credentials").validate[Seq[JenkinsCredentials]`

But the documentation doesn't discuss anything about extracting the names of the objects as a field used somewhere else...

EDIT: clarifying

My end state would be a `Seq` of `JenkinsCredentials` that are parsed from a json Object, not an array. Because of how the JSON is structured. I'd pull out the "credentials": "UUID" and "credentials":"UUID":"description" into a single object, for each potential credentials entry under "credentials"

Comment: Not quite following your ask - what are you trying to end up with? Do you have an example of the end state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out not using the `Reads[T]` methods:

```scala
//Get the key names inside of the credentials
(json \ "credentials").as[JsObject].fields.map{ case (credId, value) =>
    JenkinsCredentials(credId, (value \ "description").validate[String].get)
}
```

This works, but doesn't validate bits, and doesn't use a transformer.